# What is a way to implement a scala `Either[A,B]` structure in Koa / Javascript

Tags: javascript, scala, porting, koa, koa2

I have a few projects with Play scala and I have found it quite useful to use the scala `Either[A, B]` construct in the models so that in my controller I have something like (as an example)

```
val modelResult:Either[String, String] = ...

modelResult match {
  case Left(a) => Ok(... do something here that is meant for a 200 ....)
  case Right(err) => BadRequest(display an error in a 400)
}
```

what would be a good way to do something similar in Javascript (I use the Koa framework)

For those who are not familiar with the `Either` construct
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html

Comment: Usually it can be modeled using Promise `then`/`catch`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at one of the many FP libraries for JavaScript. [Rambda](https://ramdajs.com/) is a popular one (see [docs/#either](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#either)). You may also have a look at [daggy](https://github.com/fantasyland/daggy) for modelling co-products.

[Thinking in Rambda](http://randycoulman.com/blog/categories/thinking-in-ramda/) provides a good introduction to Rambda

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
class Either {}

class Left extends Either {
    constructor(leftValue) {
        super()
        this.leftValue = leftValue;
    }

    match(lHandler, unused) {
        return lHandler(this.leftValue);
    }
}

class Right extends Either {
    constructor(rightValue) {
        super()
        this.rightValue = rightValue;
    }

    match(unused, rHandler) {
        return rHandler(this.rightValue);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const either = ... // e.g. new Left('Test');
either.match(
    left => console.log(left),
    right => console.warn('An error occurred'),
);
```

To make this really useful, I suggest adding `map`, `flatMap`, etc.